# JVM Tomcat Spring MVC application timeout waiting for connection pool

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, tomcat

My spring application running on tomcat opens a lot of connections to localhost like this:

```
tcp6       1      0 localhost:4431          localhost:44178         CLOSE_WAIT  2393/java       
tcp6       1      0 localhost:4431          localhost:44279         CLOSE_WAIT  2393/java       
tcp6       1      0 localhost:4431          localhost:44264         CLOSE_WAIT  2393/java       
tcp6       1      0 localhost:4431          localhost:44160         CLOSE_WAIT  2393/java       
tcp6       1      0 localhost:4431          localhost:44224         CLOSE_WAIT  2393/java
```

And causes `timeout waiting for connection pool.`

Do you have an idea what the connections could be?

My `server.xml` looks like this:

```
    <?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
    <Server port="8005" shutdown="SHUTDOWN">
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JasperListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.JreMemoryLeakPreventionListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.mbeans.GlobalResourcesLifecycleListener" />
      <Listener className="org.apache.catalina.core.ThreadLocalLeakPreventionListener" />
      <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.MemoryRealm" />
      <GlobalNamingResources>
        <Resource name="UserDatabase" auth="Container"
                  type="org.apache.catalina.UserDatabase"
                  description="User database that can be updated and saved"
                  factory="org.apache.catalina.users.MemoryUserDatabaseFactory"
                  pathname="conf/tomcat-users.xml" />
      </GlobalNamingResources>
      <Service name="Catalina">
        <Connector  port="8080" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                    compression="on"
                    compressionMinSize="2048"
                    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                    compressableMimeType="
                        text/html,
                        text/xml,
                        text/plain,
                        text/css,
                        text/javascript,
                        text/json,
                        application/x-javascript,
                        application/javascript,
                        application/json,
                        application/x-font-woff,
                        image/png,
                        image/jpeg,
                        image/gif,
                        image/svg+xml
                    " 
                    connectionTimeout="20000"
                    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                    maxThreads="10000"
                    maxConnections="-1"
                    redirectPort="4431" />
        <Connector  port="4431" protocol="HTTP/1.1"
                    compression="on"
                    compressionMinSize="2048"
                    noCompressionUserAgents="gozilla, traviata"
                    compressableMimeType="
                        text/html,
                        text/xml,
                        text/plain,
                        text/css,
                        text/javascript,
                        text/json,
                        application/x-javascript,
                        application/javascript,
                        application/json,
                        application/x-font-woff,
                        image/png,
                        image/jpeg,
                        image/gif,
                        image/svg+xml
                    "
                    connectionTimeout="20000"
                    URIEncoding="UTF-8"
                    maxThreads="10000"
                    maxConnections="-1"
                    scheme="https"
                    secure="true"
                    clientAuth="false"
                    proxyPort="443" />
        <Engine name="Catalina" defaultHost="localhost">
          <Cluster className="org.apache.catalina.ha.tcp.SimpleTcpCluster"/>
          <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.LockOutRealm">
            <Realm className="org.apache.catalina.realm.UserDatabaseRealm"
                   resourceName="UserDatabase"/>
          </Realm>
          <Host name="localhost"  appBase="webapps"
                unpackWARs="true" autoDeploy="true">
            <Valve className="org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve" directory="logs"
                   prefix="localhost_access_log." suffix=".txt"
                   pattern="%h %A %u %t &quot;%r&quot; %s %b &quot;%{Referer}i&quot; &quot;%{User-Agent}i&quot;" />
          </Host>
        </Engine>
      </Service>
    </Server>
```

The port `4431` is the port of the main connector. It seems like the application calls itself.

Comment: You are likely opening connections and then never closing them when you're done with them. Track down all your opens, and gate them with closes.

Comment: I don't open connections to localhost. I use a REST API that is really slow but the API runs on another server. Why there are connections from localhost to localhost?

Comment: it is not the port of your database ? have you check for `4431` in the conf directory of tomcat?

Comment: I do not open a database connection. The application uses only a REST API as a persistence layer.

Comment: Would you be able to post more details? Is your app deployed in Tomcat or are you using an embedded container? Are you using spring boot? You could post a stripd down version of the app to github, that allows to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Yes the application is deployed on tomcat. I use spring mvc without boot. I cannot make parts of the application public.

Comment: Are parts of your app requiring SSL? You might have a redirect loop, have you tried with the dev tools on your browser?

Comment: Can you tell us more about your env? Is thera a reverse proxy in front of your tomcat cluster that handles SSL-termination? Is that proxy on the same machine? In that case my hunch would be that the redirectPort is wrong.

Comment: Yes the entire app is serving over SSL. I will check for loops between Nginx and Tomcat.

Comment: The is a load balancer in the front. After that there is a Nginx server for static assets and Tomcat for Spring MVC behind that. Nginx and Tomcat runs on the same machine and there are 4 machines in the cluster.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127373/discussion-between-revau-lt-and-robert-moszczynski).

Comment: "The application uses only a REST API as a persistence layer." - what do you mean by that? Does your application connect to any database?

Comment: What about catalina and tomcat logs?

Comment: No, the application does not connect to any database. The database and the business logic is exposed through a REST-API.

Comment: There is nothing interesting in the logs.

Answer (score 0):

It seems you have an SSL configuration not ending in tomcat, then you could remove completely the connector for 4431 port and replace the redirectPort attribute of 8080 connector with a proxyPort="443"

Answer (score 0):

To figure out what is going on in your application, I would run jconsole and see what thread it is. It is part of the Java SDK and it allows you to look at threads running in Tomcat.

Comment: I will give it a try.